# Ask Ubuntu is giving the wrong certificate

Tags: bug, google-chrome, firefox, security, askubuntu

When I go to [www.askubuntu.com](http://www.askubuntu.com) I get an error:

[image]

When I click advanced it says:

> This server could not prove that it is www.askubuntu.com; its security certificate is from stackexchange.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.
>
> NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID

This is on Google Chrome - Ubuntu 14.04, but has been reproduced on Firefox - all Ubuntu.

[Here is the Ask Ubuntu chat.](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18835430#18835430)

Just plain old [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com) is fine.

---

Edit: Now working sometimes, but not always. Same error.

Comment: The one I chose is direct duplicate, which is closed as dupe of a canonical request for better HTTPS support. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard My question isn't about meta sites though...

Comment: OK, good point, but still I'm pretty sure it's the same root issue behind the scenes.